K-groups of the ring of dual numbers
I am reading K-theory and G-theory of schemes. I get to know that the G-theory of the ring of dual numbers over a field is same as the G-theory of the field, but this is not true for K-Theory. I understand the proof of G-theory. My question is how to calculate the K-groups of the ring of dual numbers?
Thank you.

Can you please add a reference that contains your definition of the K-groups? I assume you are speaking of algebraic K-theory, for which there are several approaches.

@MartinBrandenburg I am following the algebraic K-theory book by V. Srinivas.
